# Show the rest of the text in label when label size is smaller than text length

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

Hi I have a label that contain text but the label has to be in fix size but the text doesn't not, I'm trying to produce the behavior of *Windows* when you for example *Right Click* on a folder and click on *Properties* to see the complete path, but if the path was bigger than the label you can highlight it and move to the end and you can see the rest of the text. How can I do this with Winforms c#. thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TextBox` and set the `ReadOnly` property of it to `true` and its `BorderStyle` to `None`.

[image]